# Using ifstream cannot get right size of Binary file

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

In a fragment of my application I need to get the size of binary file (Number of bytes). My function uses get() method and increments while the method returns True.

My application firstly reads the original binary file and reads correct file size. Then I insert 8 bytes at the beginning of a temp.bin file I created. Next I copy the content of the original file into the temp.bin file and in another fuction I check the size of the temp.bin file but it reads wrong size (less bytes).

Double checked the binaries using HxD and they are saved correctly. Size in HxD of the original file matched the size calculated in app. Size of temp.bin in HxD is 3d6c7 which is expected, yet the size calculated is wrong.

Expected to get similar size, temp.bin size should be higher by 8 bytes inserted at the beginning of the file.

EDIT:
I believe this is minimal example. Cannot provide the bin file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


std::streamsize get_file_size(std::ifstream &File)
{
   char byte;
   File.clear();
   File.seekg(0, File.beg);
   File.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
   std::streamsize size = 0;
   while (File.get(byte))
   {
      size++;
   }
   File.clear();
   File.seekg(0, File.beg);
   std::cout << "get_file_size: " << std::hex << size << std::endl;
   return size;
}

std::streamsize read_whole_file(std::ifstream &file, char *&ReturnedBuff, int offset)
{
   std::streamsize size = get_file_size(file);
   std::cout << "SizeIn: " << std::hex << size << std::endl;
   file.seekg(offset, file.beg);
   size = size - offset;
   ReturnedBuff = new char[size];
   if (file.read(ReturnedBuff, size))
   {
      file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
      std::cout << "SizeAfter: " << std::hex << file.gcount() << std::endl;
      return size;
   }
   file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
   return 0;
}


bool copy_file_data(std::ifstream *FileIn, std::ofstream *FileOut)
{
   char c;
   std::streamsize size = 0;
   if (!FileIn->is_open() || !FileOut->is_open())
   {
      return false;
   }
   while (*FileIn)
   {
      c = FileIn->get();
      if (FileIn->eof())
      {
         break;
      }
      size++;
      FileOut->put(c);
   }
   std::cout << "SizeInsideCopy: " << std::hex << size << std::endl;
   return true;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc != 2)
   {
      std::cout << "Put filepath to binary as arg" << std::endl;
      return -1;
   }
   std::string BinaryFilePath = argv[1];
   std::ifstream FileInput;
   std::ofstream TempFileOutput;
   std::ifstream TempFileInput;
   FileInput.open(BinaryFilePath.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
   TempFileOutput.open("temp.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
   TempFileInput.open("temp.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
   FileInput.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
   TempFileOutput.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
   TempFileInput.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

   if (!FileInput.is_open() || !TempFileOutput.is_open())
   {
      std::cout << "Cannot open files" << std::endl;
      return -2;
   }

   char s8FirmwareCrc[4] = { 0 };
   char s8FirmwareSize[4] = { 0 }; 
   unsigned int U32Crc;

   FileInput.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
   TempFileOutput.write(s8FirmwareCrc, 4); 
   TempFileOutput.write(s8FirmwareSize, 4);
   if (!copy_file_data(&FileInput, &TempFileOutput))
   {
      std::cout << "Error reading files" << std::endl;
      FileInput.close();
      TempFileOutput.close();
      TempFileInput.close();
      return -3;
   }

   char *buff = NULL;
   get_file_size(FileInput);
   read_whole_file(TempFileInput, buff, 4);


   FileInput.close();
   TempFileOutput.close();
   TempFileInput.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Console wth my comments:

```
SizeInsideCopy: 3d6bf <- original file and correct size
get_file_size: 3d6bf <- original file and correct size
get_file_size: 3d000 <- temp bin file and wrong size
SizeIn: 3d000 <- temp bin file and wrong size
SizeAfter: 3cffc <- temp bin file and wrong size - offset
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] as required here please! You also might want to read the [tour] to the end, and inform yourself in our [help] what, and how you can ask here.

Comment: Sorry for that, first post. I believe the edited post should be sufficient

Comment: What's the point of these manipulations with the temp file? They are all wrong, you cannot write to a stream and then expect the changes are reflected in the other stream. Open the temporary file for writing, write to it, close it, open it for reading. Or open for reading *and* writing, write, seek to  beginning, read. OT but this whole exercise of getting the file size is mostly meaningless. If you need to read an entire file of an unknown size, read it block by block and reallocate as needed. Or use `std::filesystem::size`.

Comment: opening a file for reading and writing at the same time from different streams is going to cause problems. Either open one at a time or use a single iostream

Comment: The goal for that app is to:
1) add 8 bytes at the start of original file (that is why I create temp file, add 8 bytes and copy the original file into temp file),
2) Calculate CRC of the modified file  without first 4 added bytes (offset),
Getting the size is needed for my CRC algorithm. Cannot use filesystem cuz of <C++17
3) save the crc at the start of the file (into the offset 4 bytes). This is not included here
Will check if closing the writing stream will affect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks n.m. and Alan Birtles
Indeed the problem was in opening simultaneously ifstream and ofstream on the same file. Having one at the time solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).